# awk: find common data between two files

Tags: shell-script, awk

**File 1 (Master Data):**

```
12345|abc  
11223|xyz  
23234|pqr
```

**File 2 (Sub set of File1):**

```
12345_ASDD|PASD|AWOP  
11223_PLDD|EVAAA ASDAS|ASDD  
23234_MJKJLO|OKEI JSN|OPIE
```

**Output:**

```
12345_ASDD|PASD|AWOP|abc  
11223_PLDD|EVAAA ASDAS|ASDD|xyz  
23234_MJKJLO|OKEI JSN|OPIE|pqr
```

**Explanation:**
First column (before underscore) of **File2** should match with first column of File1 and corresponding second column of File1 should be added to File2.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is sort order important or can this be changed during the process? Are all keys of File 1 in File 2 (and vice versa), or does one of the files have less lines than the other?

Comment: Sort order is not important until data is as expected.. All keys of File2 are in File1.. File2 is sub set of File1.. File2 have lesser lines from File1..

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if(index(i,$2)==1) print i,$1}' file1 file2...
Tried this so far.. not able to get the desired output..

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest approach is to change the FS before the second file - then for example you can do the familiar field-based lookup

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {print $0,a[$1]}' File1 FS="_" File2
```